# Best what to search for "any" field in db using EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I'm using EF Core and i'm working on a api that connects to a SQL db.

I have the following calls:

```
    public async Task<GetCar> GetCarByName(string name)
    {
        return await cardb.getCar(name);
    }
```

And

```
   public async Task<GetCar> GetCarByAnyCarField(string carFieldName, object carFieldValue)
```

The first call is pretty straight forward, but the second one i can't seem to get to work;

The "Cars" table has fields of different data types like: strings, ints, longs, decimals. Is this approach possible? Can I create one method where I give the any field by name and the data just as an object? Can this be resolved in a LINQ query?

Or is this not possible (or bad practice) and should i make separate calls for each field?

Comment: Do you mean using `.Where( x=> x.carFieldName == fieldValue)`

Comment: Why LINQ `Where`, `FirstOrDefault` and similar methods have `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` argument for providing criteria and not something like what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic method that take a where condition

```
public async Task<GetCar> GetCarByAnyCarField(Expression<Func<GetCar, bool>> predicate) {
  return await context.GetCar.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync()
}
```

Comment: What's the difference from the standard `Where(predicate)` / `FirstOrDefault{Async}(predicate)` (other than in fact limiting them - what if more than one item matches the criteria) and similar methods?

Comment: Is there someway to create a factory to return a expression for a given field